# CSS for cell padding

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I want to make all the rows in the same size, but rows height with data is large. I want to fix this row size for empty rows. Table class name is demo. 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gqgzdL8/)

[image: screenshot]

```
<?php
   while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
  {
  $id=$fet['c_id'];
  $address=$fet['address'];
   $chk=$fet["c_name"];
    $in=$in+1;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='align:center'><a class='astext' href='client_view.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'>".$fet["c_name"]."</a></td>";  
    echo "<td style='align:center'><a class='ima' href='client_details.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/edit1.png' alt='edit' style='width:20px; height:20px' title=Edit></a></td><td style='align:center'>
    <a class='ima' href='clients.php?del=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/delete1.png' alt='delete' style='width:20px;height:20px' title=Delete></a></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
      }
   if ($in < 10) {
   $empty_rows = 10 - mysql_num_rows($sql1);

    for ($m = 0; $m < $empty_rows; $m++) {
    echo '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
    }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following `CSS` in your code.

```
.demo td{        
    height:20px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gqgzdL8/2/)**

Comment: please don't repeat the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed height to tr like

```
table tr {
height: 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gqgzdL8/1/

If you need box-sizing you can use it otherwise don't use

Answer (score 1):

Try to set height and line-height for td like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gqgzdL8/3/)**

```
.demo td {
 line-height:28px;
 height:28px;
}
```